# How can I fill a map of int and vector<int> in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, containers, stdmap

I have been working with `<map>`, where I declared a map as follows:

```
map <int, vector<int> > tree;
```

I am now trying to assign values to it. My goal is to place multiple values as elements of its keys. Something like this:

```
0=null
1=>0
2=>1,0
3=>2,1,0
4=>3,2,1,0
5=>0
```

I tried to assign to the map like this, but it does not work:

```
tree[3]=vector<int>(2,1,0);
```

However, the following two ways of assigning work:

```
tree[1]=vector<int>(0);
tree[2]=vector<int>(1,0);
```

Where is the problem? How can I make a function that works as a Python dictionary?

I am not using C++11.

Comment: That's not a valid std::vector constructor call.

Comment: Does the order of ints in the vectors matter in your scenarios?

Comment: Erm... check the values, please. `vector<int>(0)` generated an *empty* vector and `vector<int>(1,0)` yields a vector with a single element that is `0`. See the [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for `std::vector`.

Answer (score 7):

With C++11, you could try:

```
tree[3]=vector<int>({2,1,0});
```

<sup>Other than that, the question could use more details and some code of what you already tried...</sup>

Comment: gives me back this error : `error: deducing from brace-enclosed initializer list requires #include <initializer_list>
view.cc:578: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’`

Comment: Do you mean `#include <vector>` ?

Comment: No. I mean `#include <initializer_list>`. Have you *read* the error message the compiler generated for you?

Comment: It shouldn't actually be necessary to state the type explicitly. On the RHS of assignments, a pure brace-init-list should work, too: `tree[3] = { 2 , 1 , 0};`

Answer (score 5):

Since you are asking for a C++03 answer, this (more verbose than C++11) solution will work.

```
tree[3].push_back(2);
tree[3].push_back(1);
tree[3].push_back(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the following two lines are not doing what you expect:

```
tree[1] = vector<int>(0);
tree[2] = vector<int>(1, 0);
```

The first parameter of the corresponding [vector's constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) is the initial size of the container. The second parameter is the value to initialize elements of the container with. So, the first line constructs an empty vector and the second line constructs a vector with one element which is initialized to 0.

As indicated by the other answers, [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) is a good option if you cannot use [C++11 features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11). However, once you upgrade to C++11, you can also initialize your map by using nested [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) as follows:

```
int main() {
    std::map<int, std::vector<int>> tree{
        {1, {0}}, {2, {1, 0}}, {3, {2, 1, 0}}, {4, { 3, 2, 1, 0 }}, {5, { 0 }}
    };

    for (auto const &kv : tree) {
        std::cout << kv.first << " =>";
        for (auto const &i : kv.second)
            std::cout << " " << i;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 1 => 0
>   2 => 1 0
>   3 => 2 1 0
>   4 => 3 2 1 0
>   5 => 0

[Code on Ideone](http://ideone.com/KLDCis)

Answer (score 1):

Without C++11, the code won't be as elegant:

```
tree[0]; // create empty vector for index 0
tree[1].push_back(0);
tree[2].push_back(1);
tree[2].push_back(0);
tree[3].push_back(2);
tree[3].push_back(1);
tree[3].push_back(0);
tree[4].push_back(3);
tree[4].push_back(2);
tree[4].push_back(1);
tree[4].push_back(0);
tree[5].push_back(0);
```

Comment: Any reason why you put this information in a _separate_ answer?

Comment: To separate C++11 from C++03. Is that something I shouldn't do in such a case?

Comment: Hmmm. I would never do this because 1) it is easy to use Markdown to structure one slightly longer answer to make it easy to keep the C++03 and C++11 parts apart, and 2) giving two answers makes it look like you just want twice the reputation. But there is no clear policy, I believe. There are meta posts on this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165831/can-a-single-user-post-two-answers-for-one-question) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155009/does-allowing-multiple-answers-by-the-same-user-make-sense-on-the-main-site).

Comment: OK, understood. I thought it would be clearer, since the information "no C++11" was only given later. But now I can't delete this answer, so please just ignore it and I won't do it again. I created my account a long time ago and forgot about it, I only started using it three weeks ago, so I still feel like a noob here :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [`std::multi_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)?

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::multimap<int, int> map;

    for (int i=1; i < 6; i++)
        for (int j=1; j < i; j++)
            map.insert(std::make_pair(i, j));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Frey points out, you can use

```
tree[3] = vector<int>({2,1,0})
```

In python-like pseudo-code, the vector constructor being used here is

```
def vector(arr)
```

The original post suggests you're trying to use a constructor of the form

```
def vector(*args)
```

which doesn't exist.

If you're not using C++11, consider using one of `vector`'s [other constructors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't particularly *like* va_args but the solution is "neater" to a degree than most as long as you (the user) don't mess it up, i.e. mixing types. Another downside is that your vector cannot contain -1, but your example case doesn't show it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>

//Unsafe but it works.
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> make_vector(T num, ...) {
    std::vector<T> result;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,num);
    for(T i = num; i != -1; i = va_arg(args,T))
        result.push_back(i);
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = make_vector(0,1,2,3,-1); //-1 to stop
    //do stuff with vector v
}
```

Comment: doesnt boost have a thing for filling vectors using commas?